# Error in multiplying matrix vector - invalid operands to binary * (have 'double *' and 'double *')

Tags: c, matrix, vector, multiplication

I'm trying to multiply a large and random matrix (NxN) and a random vector (N), using pointers. 
 Why am i getting an error type "invalid operands to binary *  (have 'double *' and 'double *')" ?
The error seems to be in  ptr3[i][j] = ptr3[i] + ptr1[i] * ptr2[k];
but I can't figure out why this doesn't work.
I'm new to C, so I still don't get pointers very well.

````
int main ()
{
    time_t t;
    double **ptr1, **ptr2, **ptr3;
    int i, j, k;
    int N = 500;
    ptr1 = (double **) malloc (sizeof (double *) * N);
    ptr2 = (double **) malloc (sizeof (double *) * N);
    ptr3 = (double **) malloc (sizeof (double *) * N);

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        ptr1[i] = (double *) malloc (sizeof (double) * N);
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        ptr2[i] = (double *) malloc (sizeof (double) * N);
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        ptr3[i] = (double *) malloc (sizeof (double) * N);

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            ptr1[i][j] = rand ();
        }
    }
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            *ptr2[i] = rand ();
    }
    t = clock();

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {

            ptr3[i] = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < N; k++)
                ptr3[i] = ptr3[i] + ptr1[i][k] * ptr2[k];

    }

   t = clock() - t;
    double time_taken = ((double)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Tempo:  %f segundos \n", time_taken);

 printf ("\n");
    return (0);
} ```
````

Comment: As the  message says: in `ptr3[i][j] = ptr3[i] + ptr1[i] * ptr2[k];` the `ptr3[i][j]` is a `double` value, but the other three are pointers, and adding/multiplying them makes no sense.

Comment: Note too that you made `ptr2` a 2D array like `ptr1` and `ptr3`, not the 1D array mentioned in the narrative and initialised in a loop.

Comment: It looks like the posted code is being changed without comment.

Comment: It's looking like a "shifting sand" question. Please copy/paste your *actual* code and leave it so that comments and answers stay relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the compiler is saying is that in the statement `ptr3[i] = ptr3[i] + ptr1[i] * ptr2[k];`, the bit which says `ptr1[i] * ptr2[k]` is attempting to `*` between two expressions which have the type `double*`. In other words, you are not allowed to multiply two pointers together. To do this properly, you need to dereference again (the `[i]` and `[k]` are dereferencing the `double**` to a `double*` already). To get this to compile, that statement should be (I added parenthesis for clarity -- they aren't actually needed):

```
*ptr3[i] = (*ptr3[i]) + (*ptr1[i]) * (*ptr2[k]);
```

That should get you to compiling, but the next problem you'll run into is a segmentation fault. Two lines above the place where you do the multiplication, you have this:

```
ptr3[i] = 0;
```

This is assigning `ptr3[i]` to be the [null pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer), which is the same as `0` in C (other languages have a different name of this value: `null`, `None`, etc). What I think you meant to do here is:

```
*ptr3[i] = 0;
```

---

As an aside, since `N` is a known, fixed value, you can choose to not deal with all the `malloc` stuff by simply saying:

```
const int N = 500;
double ptr1[N][N];
double ptr2[N][N];
// ... and so on ...
```

This is declaring `ptr1` as an *array* instead of a pointer, which is identical to a pointer in terms of memory access patterns, but [different in a number of ways](http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~mjhinek/W13/COMP2401/notes/Arrays_and_Pointers.pdf). Depending on what you are trying to learn, not dealing with dynamic memory (using `malloc` and `free`) might save you a little bit of headache for now.